# django makemigrations import error

Tags: python, django

```
  File "E:\PhytonProgects\natarelke\users\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from catalog.models import Dish
  File "E:\PhytonProgects\natarelke\catalog\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from users.models import RegModel
ImportError: cannot import name RegModel
```

try do `makemigrations` but have an error if i will remove `from users.models import RegModel` i will give another an error

```
  File "E:\PhytonProgects\natarelke\catalog\models.py", line 115, in Review
user = models.ForeignKey(RegModel, verbose_name=u'123',
NameError: name 'RegModel' is not defined
```

How i can fix it? Have it after add `dish` field in table

```
class UserFavs(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(RegModel, verbose_name=u'Пользователь',
                             related_name="user", null=True)
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, verbose_name=u'Блюдо',
                             related_name="dish")
```

Comment: You could display the RegModel class.

Comment: hm... ty so how i can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of importing the model, use a string of the form "appname.ModelName".

```
user = models.ForeignKey("users.RegModel", ...)
```

Comment: do Like u `class UserFavs(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.RegModel', verbose_name=u'Пользователь',
                             related_name="userfavs", null=True)
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, verbose_name=u'Блюдо',
                             related_name="dish")`

Comment: `  File "E:\PhytonProgects\natarelke\users\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from catalog.models import Dish
  File "E:\PhytonProgects\natarelke\catalog\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from users.models import RegModel
ImportError: cannot import name RegModel
`

Comment: Yes, the point of changing it to a string is that you now no longer need to import RegModel.

Comment: .....
users.UserFavs.dish: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'UserFavs.dish' clashes with reverse accessor for 'UserOrderItem.dish'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'UserFavs.dish' or 'UserOrderItem.dish'.
users.UserFavs.dish: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'UserFavs.dish' clashes with reverse query name for 'UserOrderItem.dish'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'UserFavs.dish' or 'UserOrderItem.dish'.

Comment: ty for the Help Fixed